# Fatal error when running r:setPlotDevice and JavaGD

Tags: java, r, netlogo

I'm running `Netlogo 6.1.0` on `macOS 10.14`. I am trying to run `plot-example1.nl` from the examples of R-Extension. I have installed `JavaGD` and `rJava`. When I try to run `setup` I get the following error:

```
Error during configuration of JavaGD device: org.nlogo.api.ExtensionException: Error in path package("JavaGD").
```

Every time `Netlogo` tries to run `r:setPlotDevice` I get this error.

Comment: I know nothing about Netlogo, but it seems like the R installation found the extensions folder has failed to install the JavaGD package or cannot access it. Note, also, that Netlogo is supposed to use the Rserve package and not the rJava package.

Comment: @juan-sebastian-lozano I think that Rserve is an alternative to R-Extension and this one needs rJava. Please see http://rserve-ext.sourceforge.net/ about this.